# Expressing angular momentum with Pauli matrics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, notation

The relation - $$(\psi^{m'}_{1/2},\boldsymbol J\psi^m_{1/2})=\frac{\hbar}{2}\boldsymbol \sigma_{m'm}$$
where $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is, I assume, the Pauli vector, appears in Weinberg, lecturs on quantum mechanics, p.115 (second edition). I'm not sure how to read this, is it - $$(\psi^{m'}_{1/2},\boldsymbol J\psi^m_{1/2})\overset{?}{=} (\psi^{m'}_{1/2}, J_1\psi^m_{1/2}) + (\psi^{m'}_{1/2}, J_1\psi^m_{1/2}) + (\psi^{m'}_{1/2},J_3\psi^m_{1/2})$$

if $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is a vector, what does the indices $m',m$ mean? Indices should be integers. Is it like kronecker's delta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is a vector, however it is more precisely a *vector of matrices*. You have one index which denotes which Pauli matrix you're using, and then the Pauli matrix has two indices because it's a matrix. To avoid confusion, let's say:
$$\boldsymbol{\sigma}=(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3)$$
that is, the index which tells us which Pauli matrix we're using is up. Then your expression can be rewritten as:
$$(\psi^{m'}_{1/2}, J^i\psi^m_{1/2})=\frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_{m'm}^i$$
where $J^i$ is the $i$-th component of angular momentum, and $\sigma_{m'm}^i$ is the $m'-m$ component of the $i$-th Pauli matrix. Note that there are no repeated indices and no summation is involved, so the expression you propose is not correct.

EDIT: There might be some confusion over the fact that the indices $m$ and $m'$ are half-integers, and more precisely can take the values $\pm 1/2$. In particular one should interpret $\sigma_{11}=\sigma_{++}$, and the others correspondigly. This can be seen as follows. Weinberg states in an unnumbered eq. just before the one mentioned by the OP:
$$J_3 \Psi_{1/2}^{\pm 1/2}=\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\Psi_{1/2}^{\pm 1/2}$$
So considering this expression for the positive sign, and taking an inner product, we obtain:
$$\left(\Psi_{1/2}^{+1/2},J_3 \Psi_{1/2}^{+ 1/2}\right)=+\frac{\hbar}{2}$$
The third Pauli matrix (corresponding to $J_3$) is:
$$\sigma_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
So it is correct identifying $+$ with the index number $1$ on the Pauli matrix and $-$ with the index number $2$.

Comment: Since the indices $\:m,m'\:$ each take values $\:-1/2,+1/2\:$ may we suppose that
\begin{equation}
\sigma^{i}_{m'm}=
\begin{cases}
\sigma^{i}_{11}  & \text{for} \quad m'=-\frac12, m=-\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{12}  & \text{for} \quad m'=-\frac12, m=+\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{21}  & \text{for} \quad m'=+\frac12, m=-\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{22}  & \text{for} \quad m'=+\frac12, m=+\frac12
\end{cases}
\tag{01}
\end{equation} ???

Comment: Sorry, why should $m$, $m'$ not be integer-valued?

Comment: Don't we have for angular momentum $\:j\:$ that $\:m=-j,-j+1,-j+2,\cdots,j-1,j\:$ in general and in present case for spin angular momentum $\:j=\frac12\:$ that $\:m=-\frac12,+\frac12\:$ ???

Comment: Yes sorry, I picked up my copy and of course as you say $m$ and $m'$ are half-integers. The interpretation you state is correct, however you need to swap $+$ and $-$. You can see this by taking the inner product of the unnumbered equation just before the one you mention (which, by the way, is at page 107, at least in my edition)

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this

Comment: +1.For me too page 107. Now, after swap we must agree that
\begin{equation}
\sigma^{i}_{m'm}=
\begin{cases}
\sigma^{i}_{11}  & \text{for} \quad m'=+\frac12, m=+\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{12}  & \text{for} \quad m'=+\frac12, m=-\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{21}  & \text{for} \quad m'=-\frac12, m=+\frac12\\
\sigma^{i}_{22}  & \text{for} \quad m'=-\frac12, m=-\frac12
\end{cases}
\tag{01-swap}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\sigma^{i}_{m'm}\equiv\sigma^{i}_{\rho'\rho}\,, \quad \rho=\frac32-m
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes that's correct!